# MySQL: How to find the maximum length of an uninterrupted sequence of certain values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table:

```
date        value
02.10.2019  1
03.10.2019  2
04.10.2019  2
05.10.2019 -1
06.10.2019  1
07.10.2019  1
08.10.2019  2
09.10.2019  2
10.10.2019 -1
11.10.2019  2
12.10.2019  1
```

How to find the maximum length of an uninterrupted sequence of positive values (`4` in that example)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  One simple method is the difference of row numbers to identify the islands:

```
select min(date), max(date), count(*) as length
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by sign(value) order by date) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by sign(value), (seqnum_1 - seqnum_2)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

This is a little hard to explain.  I find that if you stare at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference identifies the groups.

Assuming there are no gaps in the dates, another method finds the next non-positive number (if any):

```
select t.*,
       datediff(date, coalesce(next_end_date, max_date)) as num
from (select t.*,
             min(case when value <= 0 then date end) over (order by date desc) as next_end_date,
             max(date) over () as max_date
      from t
     ) t
where value > 0
order by datediff(date, coalesce(next_end_date, max_date)) desc
limit 1;
```